# What is this April flowering shrub with clusters of small flowers?

Tags: identification, shrubs

I'm trying to find out out what kind of flowering bush this could be.  It's located in Nitro, West Virginia. It smells like Gardenia. Some of the bushes are quite tall.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

My guess is Daphne bhoula...the Forward Daphne.  My goodness this one is tough.  Let's see what Bamboo has to say...! Nice find btw!  Are those leaves sort of furry and grey?

Comment: Leaves are green and not furry.

Answer (score 1):

I think it might be Elaeagnus x ebbinei? actually I'm pretty sure it is that!   although it looks as if it reverted and gone back to its wild form- pretty nice plant- but ever so unkempt!